# Difference in result while reading same file with node and python

Tags: python, node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I have been trying to read the contents of the `genesis.block` given in [this file of the Node SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/release/test/fixtures/channel/twoorgs.genesis.block) in Hyperledger Fabric using Python. However, whenever I try to read the file with Python by using

```
data = open("twoorgs.genesis.block").read()
```

The value of the `data` variable is as follows:

```
>>> data
'\n'
```

With nodejs using `fs.readFileSync()` I obtain an instance of `Buffer()` for the same file.

```
var data = fs.readFileSync('./twoorgs.genesis.block');
```

The result is

```
> data
<Buffer 0a 22 1a 20 49 63 63 ac 9c 9f 3e 48 2c 2c 6b 48 2b 1f 8b 18 6f a9 db ac 45 07 29 ee c0 bf ac 34 99 9e c2 56 12 e1 84 01 0a dd 84 01 0a d9 84 01 0a 79 ... >
```

How can I read this file successfully using Python?

Comment: Try `data = open("twoorgs.genesis.block").readlines()` or `data = open("twoorgs.genesis.block", 'rb').read()`

Comment: @StephenRauch The result is `['\n', '"']` for `readlines()`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Looks like using `rb` does the task. Please post an answer if you'd like and I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You file has a `1a` in it.  This is Ctrl-Z, which is an end of file on Windows.

So try binary mode like:

```
data = open("twoorgs.genesis.block", 'rb').read()
```